# Multiple Image Save with data in Asp.Net Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am trying to save a record along with multiple images. Order Class has Images, which is an iCollection of orderImage class in which I want to save images per record.

```
public class Order
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Invoice ID")]
    public string InvoiceId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Delivery Date")]
    public string DeliveryDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Shipping Location")]
    public int ShippingLocationId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Branch ID")]
    public string BranchId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Product Name")]
    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Product Color")]
    public string ProductColor { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Product Size")]
    public string ProductSize { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Quantity")]
    public string Quantity { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Status")]
    public string OrderStatusId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Sales Consultant")]
    public string SalesPersonId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Order Note")]
    public string OrderNote { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Delivery Note")]
    public string DeliveryNote { get; set; }

    public ICollection<OrderImage> Images { set; get; }
}

public class OrderImage
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public string Name { set; get; }
    public long Size { set; get; }
    public string Type { set; get; }
    public string Path { set; get; }
    public int orderId { set; get; }
}
```

and then I am saving the images in a different table with the orderID so that can be identified.
the controller is below.

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> NewOrderAsync(Order _order, IFormFile[] _fileObj, OrderImage _orderImage)
        {
            if (_fileObj == null || _fileObj.Length == 0)
            {
                ViewData["NullImage"] = "Please select at least one Image";
            }
            foreach (IFormFile _image in _fileObj)
            {
                string _imageExtension = Path.GetExtension(_image.FileName);
                if (_imageExtension == ".jpg" || _imageExtension == ".png" || _imageExtension == ".JPEG" || _imageExtension == ".webp")
                {
                    var _imageFileName = _order.InvoiceId + "_" + _image.FileName;
                    var _imageSave = Path.Combine(_iWebHost.WebRootPath, "OrderImage");
                    var _stream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(_imageSave, _imageFileName), FileMode.Create);

                    await _image.CopyToAsync(_stream);

                    _orderImage.Name = _imageFileName;
                    _orderImage.Type = _imageExtension;
                    _orderImage.Path = _imageSave;
                    _orderImage.Size = _image.Length;
                    _orderImage.orderId = _order.Id;

                    await _context.OrderImage.AddAsync(_orderImage);
                    ViewData["Message"] = "Image is saved";
                }
                else
                {
                    ViewData["Message"] = "Image is not saved";
                }
            }
        _context.Add(_order);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Order");
        }
```

The problem I am having is whenever I save the image, I am able to save the order records and the last image of the uploaded pictures. as per the DB when it comes to the OrderID it is 0, I tried debugging. the order id returns 0. I do need advice on if the way I do is correct. for order and orderImages there are two tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilize navigation properties. Order can have a collection of images and/or Image can have a reference to an order. When Entities are set up with Identity key columns (which should be the norm) EF won't have a PK value to provide until you call SaveChanges(). Navigation properties are the key to allow EF to defer providing FKs until the whole object graph is saved.

As a simple example:

```
public class Order
{
    [Key]
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    // Other Order fields...
    public virtual ICollection OrderImage Images { get; set; } = new List<OrderImage>();
}

public class OrderImage
{
    [Key]
    public int OrderImageId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Order")]
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
}
```

Then when you go to populate a new order and images:

```
var order = new Order
{
   // populate fields...
}

foreach (var file in files)
{
    var orderImage = new OrderImage
    {
        // copy details from file...
        Order = order
    }
    order.Images.Add(orderImage);
}

context.Orders.Add(order);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Since EF is aware of the navigation property relationships between Orders and OrderImages, when you insert a new Order and set of Images, EF will automatically work out the FK OrderId on the images to ensure the Order is saved first, assigned a new ID, then provide that OrderId to the images.

I strongly recommend reading up on navigation properties in EF as these allow EF to take over worrying about FK relationships for both writing and reading.

Comment: okay, that's neat. so helpful, Thank you so much. now if I want to retrieve the image to the order table, how would it be? I have to show one image from the collection we have inserted in the order data row, I have added as : <img src="@("~/OrderImage/"+item.Images)" asp-append-version="true"/> in the table view. I am unable to see the image and the error is: 404 on console, 
https://localhost:44310/OrderImage/System.Collections.Generic.List%601[Project.Models.OrderImage]

Comment: please check this question for more info
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63751252/retrieve-single-image-from-collection-asp-net-core