# Retrieve single image from collection ASP.NET Core

Tags: jquery, entity-framework, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, datatable

I have one model class (order.cs) which has some properties including a collection which listifies another class - orderimage.

```
public class Order
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Invoice ID")]
    public string InvoiceId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Delivery Date")]
    public string DeliveryDate { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ShippingLocation")]
    [Display(Name = "Shipping Location")]
    public string ShippingLocationId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Branch ID")]
    public string BranchId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Product Name")]
    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Product Color")]
    public string ProductColor { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Product Size")]
    public string ProductSize { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Quantity")]
    public string Quantity { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("OrderStatus")]
    [Display(Name = "Status")]
    public string OrderStatusId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Sales Consultant")]
    public string SalesPersonId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Order Note")]
    public string OrderNote { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Delivery Note")]
    public string DeliveryNote { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<OrderImage> Images { set; get; } = new List<OrderImage>();

    public virtual ShippingLocation ShippingLocation { get; set; }

    public virtual OrderStatus OrderStatus { get; set; }
}

public class OrderImage
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public string Name { set; get; }
    public long Size { set; get; }
    public string Type { set; get; }
    public string Path { set; get; }
    [ForeignKey("Order")]
    public int orderId { set; get; }
    public virtual Order Order {get; set;}
}
```

These were to save an order record along with images but the images will be saved to another table including Order ID of an order. When I have to retrieve it to the datatable I want to retrieve the first image of the collection which has been inserted for a particular order. I am receiving order details as follows in the controller.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Order()
    {
        return View(await _context.Order.ToListAsync());
    }
```

The root image folder is OrderImage and the way how the path saved on db is,

> ~/OrderImage/Luxury-Bed-Collections-Customize.jpg

Now when I retrieve on table, in the view it is

```
    @foreach (var item in Model)
       {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img src="@("~/OrderImage/"+item.Images)" asp-append-version="true" width="50px" height="50px"/>
                <span class="avatar-status bg-teal"></span>
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InvoiceId)
            </td>
        </tr>
        }
```

but all what I am receiving here is a thumbnail. in the console it is,

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Where am I making a mistake, What would be the proper way to retrieve a collection of image as a string to show. Suggestions are appreciated.

Viewing Datatable controller is below

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Order()
        {
            var _orderList = await (from ORD in _context.Order
                                    join AUR in _context.UserRoles on ORD.SalesPersonId equals AUR.UserId 
                                    join AU in _context.Users on AUR.UserId equals AU.Id
                                    join AR in _context.Roles on AUR.RoleId equals AR.Id into UserTable
                                    from AR in UserTable.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                    join OI in _context.OrderImage on ORD.Id equals OI.orderId into OrderOrderImageTable
                                    from OI in OrderOrderImageTable.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                    select new Order
                                    {
                                        InvoiceId = ORD.InvoiceId,
                                        DeliveryDate = ORD.DeliveryDate,
                                        ShippingLocationId = SL.Name,
                                        ProductName = ORD.ProductName,
                                        ProductColor = ORD.ProductColor,
                                        ProductSize = ORD.ProductSize,
                                        Quantity = ORD.Quantity,
                                        OrderStatusId = ORD.OrderStatusId,
                                        SalesPersonId = AU.FirstName,
                                        OrderNote = ORD.OrderNote,
                                        DeliveryNote = ORD.DeliveryNote,
                                        Images = ORD.Images
                                    }).ToListAsync();
            return View(_orderList);
        }
```

The Order View as requested

```
@model IEnumerable<Order>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Title -->
    <title> ZETA -  Business in Simple </title>
    <!-- Favicon -->
    <link rel="icon" href="~/Theme/img/brand/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon" />
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">ZETA</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <h4>Order</h4>
    <hr />
    <!-- main-content opened -->
    <div class="main-content horizontal-content">
        <!-- container opened -->
        <div class="container">
            <!-- breadcrumb -->
            <div class="breadcrumb-header justify-content-between">
                <div class="my-auto">
                    <div class="d-flex">
                        <h4 class="content-title mb-0 my-auto">Order</h4><span class="text-muted mt-1 tx-13 mr-2 mb-0"> / View All</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex my-xl-auto right-content">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                        <a class="modal-effect btn btn-outline-primary btn-block" data-effect="effect-scale" data-toggle="modal" href="#addOrderModal">Add New</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- breadcrumb -->
            <!-- row opened -->
            <div class="row row-sm">
                <div class="col-xl-12">
                    <div class="card mg-b-20">
                        <div class="card-header pb-0">
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="table-responsive">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                                        <div id="example_filter" class="dataTables_filter">
                                            <label>
                                                <input type="search" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Search..." aria-controls="example">
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <table id="newOrderTab" class="table text-md-nowrap">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th class="border-bottom-0">
                                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Images)
                                            </th>
                                            <th class="border-bottom-0">
                                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.InvoiceId)
                                            </th>
                                            <th class="border-bottom-0">
                                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ShippingLocationId)
                                            </th>
                                            <th class="border-bottom-0">
                                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ProductName)
                                            </th>
                                            <th class="border-bottom-0">
                                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SalesPersonId)
                                            </th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        @foreach (var item in Model)
                                        {
                                        <tr>
                                            @foreach (var image in item.Images)
                                            {
                                                <td>
                                                    <img src="@("~/OrderImage/"+ image.Name)" asp-append-version="true" width="50px" height="50px" />
                                                    <span class="avatar-status bg-teal"></span>
                                                </td>
                                            }
                                            <td>
                                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InvoiceId)
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ShippingLocationId)
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductName)
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SalesPersonId)
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        }
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- JQuery min js -->
    <script src="~/Theme/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#newOrderTab").DataTable({
                "responsive": true,
                "paging": false,
                "info": false,
                "bFilter": false,
                "autoWidth": false,
                "dom": 'Bfrtip',
                "buttons": [
                    { extend: 'excel'}, 
                    { extend: 'pdf'},
                    { extend: 'print'},
                    { extend: 'colvis'} 
                ]
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Required Screen shots of order view controller

[Order Result View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ejo7.png)

[Order Image Result View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYpYA.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in Order action you have updated is correct.

But I think for **one-to-many or many-to-many** relational tables, in ef core, using **[Include](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data)** is the simplest and most direct way.

**Include** is the most commonly used method to get the data of the associated table in ef core.

Since you did not provide the code of other tables, I will provide you with examples based on the `Order` table and `OrderImage` table you gave.

Action:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Order()
    {
         
        return View(await _context.Order.Include(x=>x.Images).ToListAsync());
    }
```

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Order>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Order";
    Layout = null;
    var maxCount = Model.Max(x => x.Images.Count);
}
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Title -->
    <title> ZETA -  Business in Simple </title>
    <!-- Favicon -->

    <link href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#newOrderTab").DataTable({
                "responsive": true,
                "paging": false,
                "info": false,
                "bFilter": false,
                "autoWidth": false,
                "dom": 'Bfrtip',
                "buttons": [
                    { extend: 'excel' },
                    { extend: 'pdf' },
                    { extend: 'print' },
                    { extend: 'colvis' }
                ]
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">ZETA</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <h4>Order</h4>
    <hr />
    <!-- main-content opened -->
    <div class="main-content horizontal-content">
        <!-- container opened -->
        <div class="container">
            <!-- breadcrumb -->
            <div class="breadcrumb-header justify-content-between">
                <div class="my-auto">
                    <div class="d-flex">
                        <h4 class="content-title mb-0 my-auto">Order</h4><span class="text-muted mt-1 tx-13 mr-2 mb-0"> / View All</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex my-xl-auto right-content">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                        <a class="modal-effect btn btn-outline-primary btn-block" data-effect="effect-scale" data-toggle="modal" href="#addOrderModal">Add New</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- breadcrumb -->
            <!-- row opened -->
            <div class="row row-sm">
                <div class="col-xl-12">
                    <div class="card mg-b-20">
                        <div class="card-header pb-0">
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="table-responsive">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                                        <div id="example_filter" class="dataTables_filter">
                                            <label>
                                                <input type="search" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Search..." aria-controls="example">
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <table id="newOrderTab" class="table text-md-nowrap">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            @for (int i = 0; i < maxCount; i++)
                                            {
                                                <th class="border-bottom-0">
                                                    Images[@i]
                                                </th>
                                            }
                                            <th class="border-bottom-0">
                                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.InvoiceId)
                                            </th>
                                            <th class="border-bottom-0">
                                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ShippingLocationId)
                                            </th>
                                            <th class="border-bottom-0">
                                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ProductName)
                                            </th>
                                            <th class="border-bottom-0">
                                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SalesPersonId)
                                            </th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        @foreach (var item in Model)
                                        {
                                        <tr>
                                            @for (int i = 0; i < maxCount; i++)
                                            {
                                                if (i >= item.Images.Count())
                                                {
                                                    <td>no pic</td>
                                                }
                                                else
                                                {
                                                    <td>
                                                        <img src="@("~/OrderImage/"+ item.Images.Skip(i*1).Take(1).FirstOrDefault().Path)" asp-append-version="true" width="50px" height="50px" />
                                                        <span class="avatar-status bg-teal"></span>
                                                    </td>
                                                }

                                            }

                                            <td>
                                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InvoiceId)
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ShippingLocationId)
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductName)
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SalesPersonId)
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        }
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- JQuery min js -->

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the view result based on these:

[image]

### Update

Based on your `OrderImage` structure, the `Size`  field in your `OrderImage` class is of type `long`, while in the database, the `Size` field of the `OrderImage` table is of `Varchar` type. The `varchar` type should match the `string` in class.

Therefore, you only need to Change the Size field in the OrderImage class to `string` type.

```
public class OrderImage
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public string Name { set; get; }
    public string Size { set; get; }//change this line
    public string Type { set; get; }
    public string Path { set; get; }
    [ForeignKey("Order")]
    public int orderId { set; get; }
    public virtual Order Order {get; set;}
}
```

Or If you want the size to be long type, then please change the size type of the database to **`BIGINT`**

### Update2

If you only want to show the first image in the table, you can use the following code:

```
<table id="newOrderTab" class="table text-md-nowrap">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>

                                            <th class="border-bottom-0">
                                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Images)
                                            </th>

                                            <th class="border-bottom-0">
                                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.InvoiceId)
                                            </th>
                                            <th class="border-bottom-0">
                                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ShippingLocationId)
                                            </th>
                                            <th class="border-bottom-0">
                                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ProductName)
                                            </th>
                                            <th class="border-bottom-0">
                                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SalesPersonId)
                                            </th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        @foreach (var item in Model)
                                        {
                                            <tr>

                                                <td>
                                                    <img src="@("~/OrderImage/"+ item.Images.FirstOrDefault().Path)" asp-append-version="true" width="50px" height="50px" />
                                                    <span class="avatar-status bg-teal"></span>
                                                </td>

                                                <td>
                                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InvoiceId)
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ShippingLocationId)
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductName)
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SalesPersonId)
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        }
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221189/discussion-on-answer-by-yongqing-yu-retrieve-single-image-from-collection-asp-ne).

Answer (score 0):

`item.Images` is `ICollection<OrderImage>`, so in this line: 
`<img src="@("~/OrderImage/"+item.Images)" ...` you tried to concatenate `string` with `ICollection<OrderImage>`.

You should iterate over item.Images like this (fix html on yourself):

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        @foreach(var image in item.Images)
        {
            <td>
                <img src="@("~/OrderImage/"+image.Path)" asp-append-version="true" width="50px" height="50px"/>
                <span class="avatar-status bg-teal"></span>
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InvoiceId)
            </td>
        }
    </tr>
}
```

Or, if you need only one image, write this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="@("~/OrderImage/"+item.Images.First().Path)" asp-append-version="true" width="50px" height="50px"/>
            <span class="avatar-status bg-teal"></span>
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InvoiceId)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

And don't forget to `Include` the Images in your controller.

Comment: I am getting an Invalid cast error, Images are ICollection when the properties of order images are string. This is where I was stuck in.

Error: InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Int64'.

Comment: The controller is updated with the question. Please have a look.